# Model inside Model changes result in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a many to many db call for my CI models and to do this I'm calling a model from inside a model...if there is a better way I'm all ears!

I have three models:

```
Models:
- events
- children
- eventChildren
```

They do basic CRUD operations. In my `events` model I have a `GetEvents` method that accepts a `withChildren` parameter. If the `withChildren` parameter is passed I want to get the children associated with the event.

When I call the `eventChildren` model from inside the `events` model that's when the results come back funny. I've narrowed it down to the `$this->db->get('eventChildren');` call from inside the `eventChildren` model. When this call is made suddenly I return multiple events rather than a single event.

Code:

```
if(isset($options['eventId']) && isset($options['withChildren']))
{
    // Get ID's of children that are tied to the event.
    $this->load->model('eventChildren_model', 'eventChildren');
    $this->load->model('children_model', 'children');

    $eventChildren = $this->eventChildren->GetEventChildren(array('eventId' => $options['eventId']));

    // Loop over those ID's and get the children from the children table
    $children = array();

    foreach($eventChildren as $group)
    {
        $child = $this->children->GetChildren(array('childId' => $group->childId));
        array_push($children, $child);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($children);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

If I comment out this line of code I return a single event. If I uncomment this line of code I return all events.

```
$eventChildren = $this->eventChildren->GetEventChildren(array('eventId' => $options['eventId']));
```

This is related to the `$this->db->get('eventChildren');` call. Once that call is made the events act weird.

Example Return without making external model call:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [eventId] => 2
            ...
        )

)
```

Example Return when calling external model:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [childId] => 8
            ...
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [childId] => 10
            ...
        )
)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [eventId] => 1
            ...
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [eventId] => 2
            ...
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [eventId] => 3
            ...
        )
)
```

Sorry for all the code. I'm final goal is to create a Many to Many object that adds children to the events so I can easily display this from within my views. Everything I've read on here has discouraged the practice of loading models from within models, but I don't see a better way of doing it. I tried both DataMapper and Doctrine and couldn't get either to work successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Events Model (GetEvents): (Note: _p() is a helper function that just outputs a `print_r()` wrapped with `<pre>` tags)

```
function GetEvents($options = array())
{
    // default values
    $options = _default(array('sortDirection' => 'asc'), $options);

    // Add where clauses to query
    $qualificationArray = array('eventId', 'eventStatus');
    foreach($qualificationArray as $qualifier)
    {
        if(isset($options[$qualifier])) $this->db->where($qualifier, $options[$qualifier]);
    }

    // If limit / offset are declared (usually for pagination) then we need to take them into account
    if(isset($options['limit']) && isset($options['offset'])) $this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
    else if(isset($options['limit'])) $this->db->limit($options['limit']);

    // sort
    if(isset($options['sortBy'])) $this->db->order_by($options['sortBy'], $options['sortDirection']);

    // add children to the event
    if(isset($options['eventId']) && isset($options['withChildren'])) 
    {           
        // Get ID's of children that are tied to the event.
        $this->load->model('eventChildren_model', 'eventChildren');
        $this->load->model('children_model', 'children');

        $eventChildren = $this->eventChildren->GetEventChildren(array('eventId' => $options['eventId']));

        // Loop over those ID's and get the children from the children table
        $children = array();
        foreach($eventChildren as $group)
        {
            $child = $this->children->GetChildren(array('childId' => $group->childId));
            array_push($children, $child);
        }

        echo "Children:\n";
        _p($children);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('events');
    if($query->num_rows() == 0) return false;

    _p($query->result());

    if(isset($options['eventId']))
    {
        // If we know that we're returning a singular record, then let's just return the object
        return $query->row(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // If we could be returning any number of records then we'll need to do so as an array of objects
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

eventChildren Model (GetEventChildren method)

```
function GetEventChildren($options = array())
{
    // default values
    $options = _default(array('sortDirection' => 'asc'), $options);

    // Add where clauses to query
    $qualificationArray = array('eventChildrenId', 'eventId', 'childId');
    foreach($qualificationArray as $qualifier)
    {
        if(isset($options[$qualifier])) $this->db->where($qualifier, $options[$qualifier]);
    }

    // If limit / offset are declared (usually for pagination) then we need to take them into account
    if(isset($options['limit']) && isset($options['offset'])) $this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
    else if(isset($options['limit'])) $this->db->limit($options['limit']);

    // sort
    if(isset($options['sortBy'])) $this->db->order_by($options['sortBy'], $options['sortDirection']);

    $query = $this->db->get('eventChildren');
    if($query->num_rows() == 0) return false;

    if(isset($options['eventChildrenId']))
    {
        // If we know that we're returning a singular record, then let's just return the object
        return $query->row(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // If we could be returning any number of records then we'll need to do so as an array of objects
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**SUMMARY**

My problem was in the `event_model` file where I was making a call to an external model before finishing my initial call, thus overwriting the main DB call. I had to move that code just below `$query = $this->db->get('events');` and everything worked.

A huge thank you to @landons for helping me through this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally see no problem in loading models from other models.  That actually is a good way of keeping shared logic separate.  So, keeping it DRY (don't repeat yourself) calls for that approach at times.

I'm a little confused by the fact you're outputting two arrays in the second output example (your code only has one print_r() call).  Does the child load function have a print_r()?  Does it call the same function again?  Does your $this->db->get('eventChildren') call return a result() or a first_row()?

I can't help much more without seeing your eventChildren model's GetEventChildren() function...

Comment: I was trying to avoid posting the entire model to keep the question short, but that being said I'm using the following example http://heybigname.com/2009/08/28/how-to-write-a-better-model-in-code-igniter/ I do have two `$this->db->get()` calls, but their are in each model. I'll update my question with both Models.

Comment: Getting closer.  Now, what parameters are you passing in, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: I'm grabbing the `eventId` from the URL and passing it as follows: `$event = $this->events->GetEvents(array('eventId' => $eventId, 'withChildren' => TRUE));` - When I make the `$this->db->get()` call in the `eventChildren_model` it changes to return from the `event_model`...it's really strange.

Comment: OK, looks good.  What's your _p() function do?

Comment: It's a simple helper function I wrote that simple outputs an array with `echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>";` because I got tired of writing that over and over again. In the code I'm using it to step through to see what's being returned.

Comment: Ah. Got it!  Your qualifier loop is setting your where clause for the get('events') call, right?  BUT, you're passing control on to the other models before you actually get the result, which is resetting your query, and is therefore now returning all results.  Right after your _p($query->result()) call, try var_dump($this->db->last_query()) and you'll see what I mean

Comment: I see what you mean! So by making the call to my second external model I'm not completing my first call. I could prevent this by moving the IF check under the `$this->db->get()` call inside `events_model`...let me try that out.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I wish I had more than 15 points to give.

Answer (score 0):

Something's definitely making another call, like landons said. Also, there's a high probability of variable names overlapping since none of the two `print_r`s from the second example returns a similar result to the first one.